# InstantRun: Couldn't apply code changes

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.0

Android Studio 2.0 added the new instant run feature, but it doesnt work....

```
    InstantRun: Couldn't apply code changes 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at 
com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.handleHotSwapPatch(Server.java:455) at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.handlePatches(Server.java:402) at 
com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.access$500(Server.java:61) at 
com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server$SocketServerReplyThread.handle(Server.java:311
)
```

any suggestions?

How do I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows you can go to

```
File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Instant Run
```

Disable it from there